# How to handle mouseover event in EaselJS?

Tags: mouseover, easeljs

I'm using EaselJS and I'd like to change (slightly enlarge) images while mouse is hovering over them. It seems that mouseover and mouseout events would be a good way to do it.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#event_mouseover

However, there are no examples in the docs, or at least I couldn't find any. I tried googling but without luck.

I tried something like this:

```
stage.enableMouseOver();
var btn  = new createjs.Bitmap("mybtn.png");
btn.mouseover = function() {
    btn.x++;
};
```

and found out that this works:

```
btn.onMouseOver = function() {
    btn.x++;
};
```

but docs say this variant is deprecated and one should use events. What's the proper way?

Comment: Check out the examples and tutorials that are part of the EaselJS GitHub repository - there are lots! https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/

Comment: Thanks Lanny, those help a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `addEventListener` as shown in this example (every time you move your mouse over the circle, the alpha/transparency changes):

http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/U3PYD/

```
circle.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
   circle.alpha *= .80;
   stage.update();
});
```

It assumes that you've called enableMouseOver as [documented](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver) as well:

```
stage.enableMouseOver(20);
```

Comment: It's too bad the performance hit on this is significant.  Just enabling mouseover events (without actually adding any handlers) causes a huge performance impact in my app.

Comment: Yeah -- it needs to compute the hit test regions as you move your mouse around, so it's going to be a performance hit.